# Get iphone app UUID automatically for Distribution

Tags: ios

For an small software company, that does not have an enterprise size number of employees and due to the limit of distribution via testflight for covit related apps, cannot market the ios app properly.

For each distribution need to ask the customers separately for their UUID.

I have searched the stackoverflow and web and cannot find any suitable solution for that. Uploading to appstore is also not possible due to limitation of distribution of covit related apps.
Is their any other way to distribute? like paid services. That will collect the uuid automatically and the clients can download the apps from there.

Comment: Sounds like you should deploy it as a custom B2B app in App Store Connect and then distribute use MDM (if devices are managed) or redemption codes if they are not.

Comment: for B2B, the client need to register themselves in the apple business program. But I need to distribute with out that hastle on the client side. And how to deploy in app store connect as all the covit related apps are prohibited?

Comment: B2B is really your best option.  If you use ad-hoc distribution then you need all of the UDIDs, you need to recompile each time you have to add a device and the builds will only work for 6 months before they need to be re-installed.  Setting up with Apple Business Manager isn't too difficult and since the apps will be signed by Apple, they won't expire or have UDID restrictions

Comment: for covit related beacons, app are rejected by apple during review. Can I do B2B without apple review my app?

Comment: No, your app is reviewed, but the review standards are different for B2B apps than for general App Store apps. It may still be rejected, but it worth a try. Your only other workable solution would be for the company to enrol in an enterprise membership.